# I have an InvalidCastException despite using EF Core HasConversion

Tags: entity-framework-core

On EF Core 2.1.3, I use a conversion yet I have an `InvalidcastException`.
Note that `MyProperty` has the proper casts required by the code below.

In the context:

```
builder.Entity<MyTable>().Property(o => o.MyProperty).HasMyPropertyConversion();
```

In some extensions class:

```
public static PropertyBuilder<MyProperty> HasMyPropertyConversion(this PropertyBuilder<MyProperty> property)
            => property.HasConversion(
                myProperty => (long)myProperty,
                value => (MyProperty)value);
```

Example that fails:

```
public void ThisFails(long value)
{
    var _ = _myContext
                .MyTable
                .Where(x => x.MyProperty == value)
                .ToList();
}
```

Examples that work:

```
public void ThisWorks()
{
    var _ = _myContext
                .MyTable
                .Where(x => x.MyProperty == 10L)
                .ToList();
}

public void ThisWorksAWell(long value)
{
    var _ = _myContext
                .MyTable
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.MyProperty == value)
                .ToList();
}
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException
Invalid cast from 'System.Int64' to 'MyProject.MyProperty'.
```

It seems the SQL generation with a parameter fails. Note that I cannot write an In memory test that reproduces it.

UPDATE:

I made a [repro](https://github.com/FrancoisM/EfCoreIssue) with both a local db and an in memory db tests.

UPDATE2:

The issue is solved in net core 3.0